# What is the expression to suggest a few dates and times to meet?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests

Let's say a friend of mine tells me the following:

> Nice! Let’s meet up for a drink this week.

And I want to say, "Sure let's do it. I will propose a few ..., and you tell me if either of them works for you."

I cannot come up with an idiom or other expression that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say

> I'll send a couple of dates and times. Let me know if any of them work for you.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no standard idiom available for this job. What I hear and use most often is:

> I'll send you some suggested dates and times.

You might say:

> I'll send you some options and let me
>   know what works for you.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *pencil it in* or *pencil you in* is sometimes used jokingly among busy friends in instances like this. See def. 2 From *NOAD*:

> **pencil something in 1** fill in an area or shape with pencil strokes : *a lot of the outlines had been penciled in.* **2** arrange, forecast, or note down something provisionally or tentatively : *May 15 was penciled in as the date for the meeting*. • (**pencil someone in**) make a provisional or tentative arrangement with or for someone : *he was penciled in for surgery at the end of the month.*

*Pencil* is used because the plan is tentative and pencil can easily be erased. In some circumstances this idiom can be used as a not-so-subtle way of saying the meeting will never happen (i.e. "Sure, I'll pencil that in next week") but among friends who obviously want to get together, it can be a way of gently poking fun at someone's busy schedule while letting them know you really want to get together. You could say:

> Sure, let's do it. I'm free   Tuesday and Thursday evening. Can you pencil me in?

Re-reading your question, I realized the crux has more to do with what to call the dates and times you can meet. I think the wording of my example works well—just calling them the *times that you're free*. Of course, if there is some romantic interest, you could also call them the times you are *available* with a slight emphasis on that word.

Comment: "I'll pencil you in," etc., may be obsolete. Haven't heard it in a long time - since the days of the Filofax.

Comment: @The Raven: I think it's still got [mileage](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=pencil+you+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)—especially when said tongue in cheek.

Comment: I think your answer is the sentence before: "I'm free Tuesday and Thursday, how about you?"

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to talk about schedule openings and time slots:

> I have several openings in my schedule this week. I'll send you those time slots and you can see if any of them work for you.

Comment: I thought about it too, and I'd use "time slots and openings" for formal meeting. We both are busy, hence we need more than one suggestion to mutually agree on the date and time. However, I just want to informally get together with a friend for a drink or two. Your suggestion seems perfunctory to me.

Comment: If it's that informal, why not just say "Let's get together next week. When is good for you?"

Comment: My friends and I like to jokingly use "My people will call your people" - we're all crazy-busy, but none of us actually has "people", so it's more aspirational humor than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

A few sentences that seem reasonable

"Sure let's do it. I'll propose a few free days, and you tell me if either of them work for you."

"Sure let's do it. I'll let you know my availability over the next few days, and you let me know when best suits you.

(You can replace **days** with times, evenings, mornings etc to be more time specific)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

> I'll propose a few days, and you tell me if either works for you...

Answer (score 0):

I just say, "Great, how is Monday, November 20th at noon?"  I find the whole process goes quickly when someone takes that first step and gets literal with the date. :)